# Turing Machine - Analyze brackets

Tags: turing-machines

For a practical task, we are asked to provide the transition table for a Turing machine that validates the number of open brackets is equal to the number of closing brackets.
The only tape symbols allowed are ( ) E B 
If the number of brackets is equal (opening brackets = closing brackets) then the machine must halt in-state 'yes' and if they are not equal than it must halt in-state 'no'

Any clarification on this would be greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: Do you accept `)(` or do you require the brackets to match properly?

Comment: Honestly that seems to be a topic of debate but from what i understand we can accept )(

Comment: Next question: are you asking us to do your homework? Can you try solving it and when you get stuck, ask a specific question that would help you get unstuck? This sites wants you to ask your own questions, rather than someone else's.

Comment: I am not asking you do to my homework, I have been stuck in the sense I don't know where to start. Our textbook speaks broadly on turing machines. I had the possible idea of using increment and decrement statements to increment everytime an open bracket is discovered and decrement when a close bracket is discovered and if the counter is on 0 at the end of the tape than it should halt but that doesnt make sense to execute on a tape... Just a pointer in the right direction would be appreciated as I  have no idea where to start.

Comment: Well, the amount of brackets is not bounded, so you can't use states to keep the count of brackets, so you have to decide how to keep count on the tape.

Comment: Then you need to use states and symbols to mark things on the tape and move back and forth between the input and your bookkeeping. At least, that's how I'd do it.

Comment: Is that a useful answer?

Comment: We are not allowed to use anything other than the ( ) E B... The significance of what E and B is?

Comment: But thank you so much for taking the time :)

Comment: I suppose E and B are just two more symbols you can use. Ask your professor?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like the only thing you care about is whether *the number of open brackets equals the number of close brackets*. In which case, I'd recommend an algorithm something like this:

- Look for an open bracket.

  - If you can't find one, look for a close bracket.

    - If you find one, reject. Otherwise, accept.
  - If you can find one, erase it.
- Look for a close bracket.

  - If you can't find one, reject.
  - If you can find one, erase it.

The exact mechanics of searching for brackets are up to you, but if you need more guidance, I'd recommend using one of your spare symbols ($E$ for empty) to mark empty patches of tape (everything to either side of the input) and the other ($B$ for bracket deleted) to mark things you've erased. That way you can tell when you reach the edge of the input string.

Answer (score 1):

Scan left to right, erase the first '(' (i.e., overwrite with some mark), go back to the start and erase the first ')', go back and start over. Accept if no '(' or ')' left.

This just matches '(' and ')', not proper nesting!